How to create Google Cloud task sheduled on time?
I need to create Google cloud task with long time of retry (a year for example), this will be simple post request to endpoint of my application.
I created task with
       const task = {
            ...
            scheduleTime: {
                      seconds: expirationAtSeconds,
            }
        }
       const [response] = await this.taskClient.createTask(request);

Task created successfully, but I want to delay for next execution at 17202815 seconds, this means task must raise 2024-12-01, but task run immediately in seconds, not how I expected. What I doing wrong?
More common question - How I can use Cloud Tasks to schedule a function execution on a delay?

Your timestamp is wrong. Use this one 1733007600

Ups, you are right, maybe need more seconds, but I try to increase time and receive message "Uncaught Error Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: The Task.scheduleTime, 2024-11-30T15:00:00-08:00, is too far in the future. Schedule time must be no more than 720h in the future.." You can write your advice as solution. Interesting what TTL time allow Firebase? Is it possible more than 30 day?

The maximum scheduled time for a task based on Cloud Tasks quotas and limits is 30 days.

You may follow this workaround wherein 2 cloud tasks were created and the second one will be triggered once the first task reached the max schedule time.

Posting my previous comment as an answer.
Adding to @guillaumeblaquiere's comment:
Based on this documentation on Cloud Tasks quotas and limits, the maximum scheduled time for a task is 30 days.
I would suggest following this workaround wherein 2 cloud tasks were created and the second one will be triggered once the first task reached the max schedule time.
